# a trick one: SQL select and mach

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables like this:

```
a x1 1

b y2 2
```

,

```
x1 0

x2 0

x3 0

x4 0

y1 0

y2 0

y3 0
```

,
and I wish to have this table:

```
a x1 1

a x2 0

a x3 0

a x4 0

b y1 1 

b y2 0

b y3 0
```

Any one know how to do it? thanks so much!

Comment: What decides that a goes only with x and b only with y? i.e. you need a & b also in the second table.

Comment: You haven't provided matching criteria, so it's hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the original question before the edit.

You need a [CROSS JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx):

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(Col1 VARCHAR(10)
                , Col2 VARCHAR(10), );

INSERT INTO #Table1
VALUES
      ('a'
     , 'x1'),
      ('b'
     , 'x4');

CREATE TABLE #Table2(Col1 VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #Table2
VALUES
      ('x1'),
      ('x2'),
      ('x3'),
      ('x4');
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT A.Col1
    , B.Col1
FROM   #Table1 AS A
      CROSS JOIN #Table2 AS B;
```

RESULT:

[image]

After the edits to the question this will produce the results that you need:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(Col1 VARCHAR(10)
                , Col2 VARCHAR(10)
                , Col3 INT);

INSERT INTO #Table1
VALUES
      ('a'
     , 'x1'
     , 1),
      ('b'
     , 'x4'
     , 2);

CREATE TABLE #Table2(Col1 VARCHAR(10)
                , Col2 INT);

INSERT INTO #Table2
VALUES
      ('x1'
     , 0),
      ('x2'
     , 0),
      ('x3'
     , 0),
      ('x4'
     , 0),
      ('y1'
     , 0),
      ('y2'
     , 0),
      ('y3'
     , 0);
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT A.Col1
    , B.Col1
    , CASE
         WHEN B.Col1 LIKE '%1' THEN 1
         ELSE B.Col2
      END
FROM   #Table1 AS A
      CROSS JOIN #Table2 AS B
WHERE  (A.Col1 = 'a'
       AND B.Col1 LIKE 'x%'
      )
      OR (A.Col1 = 'b'
         AND B.Col1 LIKE 'y%'
        );
```

RESULT:

[image]

Note you need to be careful using CROSS JOINS as it could lead to massive result sets

Comment: Thanks, I just modifid my question and do you think its crossing join?

Comment: @Wayne actually you can still use CROSS JOIN, but it all depends on what is it you are trying to solve. Maybe some context could produce better answers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly but seems like you'll have to sub-string in order to join between the two tables.  I don't get where the third column is coming from; just looks like you are setting it to "1" every time the group (col1) changes.

```
with t1(col1, col2, col3)
as (
select 'a','x1',1 from dual union all 
select 'b','y2',2 from dual
),
 t2(col1,col2)
as (
select 'x1',0 from dual union all
select 'x2',0 from dual union all
select 'x3',0 from dual union all
select 'x4',0 from dual union all
select 'y1',0 from dual union all
select 'y2',0 from dual union all
select 'y3',0 from dual 

)

select  t1.col1, t2.col1, 
        case when row_number() over (partition by t1.col1 order by rownum) > 1 
             then 0 
             else 1
        end col3
from t2 join t1
on substr(t1.col2,1,1) = substr(t2.col1,1,1)
order by 1, 2
```